Antd table does not fix expandable column icon to the right
I have an antd table
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/charming-hooks-pxhjkx?file=%2Findex.js
     <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    expandable={{
      fixed: "right",
      expandedRowRender: (record) => (
        <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{record.description}</p>
      ),
      expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) =>
        expanded ? (
          <MinusCircleTwoTone onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)} />
        ) : (
          <PlusCircleTwoTone onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)} />
        ),
    }}
  />            

The table has an expandable property, which takes a fixed property. When I set it to right, the left class gets applied and hence does not get fixed to the right when the row is long.
enter image description here
Antd Docs: https://ant.design/components/table#expandable
When i change fixed to left, the styles applied stay the same as when the value is right, and get removed when it is set to false
https://ant.design/components/table#expandable

.ant-table-row-expand-icon-cell {
  right: 0px !important;
}
 

This might help!
